# how to Enable the "Data QnA" feature on Google Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I wish to try the Google Bigquery Data QnA feature. But, I am unable to find any documentation about how to **Enable** the Data QnA feature

with ref. to https://medium.com/daas-labs/trying-out-data-qna-on-bigquery-and-google-sheets-e47939fddf25
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfQAB.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QnA on [BigQuery is currently in Alpha stage](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/introducing-data-qna). I recommend to keep an eye on the BigQuery [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes).

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the alpha program, you can enable it from

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://g.co/cloud/data-qna to express your interest in trying out Data QnA feature.

Please note as specified in the form's description:
`Note that while we aim to admit additional customers, filling out this form does not guarantee access.`

I'm a Googler working on the Data QnA feature, and I'm happy, excited and proud to learn that there is growing interest amongst the BigQuery community to try this out. :)